# How to show coincident point with different symbology in webgis?

Tags: arcgis-server, point, arcgis-silverlight-api

our team have develop an webgis using ArcGIS silverlight API 3.1 .we have some points in database.These points are save in a table in sql server 2008R2 not in Geodatabase.The points have same longitudes and latitudes. I want to show these points with different symbols( colors or sizes) . I surf in the internet and found [clustering](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/help/index.html#//016600000008000000) . But the problem is that i have coincident points and clustering is use when the latitude and longitude of point are different. How can i show my points in webgis ?

Thanks for advance

Comment: Would you consider using various symbology for different points? I ended up in a similar situation recently and was forced to use circles of different radius and color to see them on top of each other. How many points do you have overlapping?

Comment: maximum points in same lat and long are 15 points.